# How to allow spaces in filename generated by using pdftk in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, extjs, pdftk

I am working in JavaScript (ExtJs framework) and I use pdftk to generate pdf / .xlsx file. I want to give space in filename. How can I  do this?

E.g.- I want 'my file.pdf' name instead of 'myfile.pdf'.

Comment: why extjs tag if you're using pdftk?

Comment: I am using ExtJs framework and pdftk to generate pdf